# Attraente e seducente, ma in modo innocente

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Sto cercando un aggettivo che corrisponda al significato di

[Winsome](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/winsome):

> - Attractive or appealing in a fresh, innocent way.
> - Charming, often in a childlike or naive way.

- I vari dizionari suggeriscono aggettivi come, '*seducente, attraente o affascinante*', ma nessuno di questi ha la specifica connotazione dell'aspetto *innocente, non malizioso* di *winsome*.
- Altro termine suggerito è '*amabile*'  al quale manca la connotazione dell'attraenza.

Esiste in italiano un aggettivo che racchiuda questi due aspetti?

Comment: "di bell'aspetto"? Purtroppo si riferisce solo all'aspetto fisico, non andrebbe bene nell'esempio del dizionario "a winsome smile"

Answer (score 10):

Non esistono aggettivi che corrispondano perfettamente all’accezione dell’inglese *winsome*, e che faccian riferimento soprattutto a un’innocenza infantile. Per trovare qualcosa che ci si avvicini, dobbiamo ricorrere a *grazioso* (derivato di *grazia*, ossia «l’insieme delle caratteristiche estetiche o di comportamento che rendono qcn. o qcs. attraente e affascinante», *[De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/grazia)*) oppure a *[leggiadro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/leggiadro)*, aggettivo dal sapore letterario.

Va da sé che l’innocenza è quasi un presupposto della bellezza di chi è leggiadro o grazioso. Il *Vocabolario degli Accademici della Crusca*, prima impressione (1612), alla voce «[Leggiadria](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?E=310;1451748;&c1=113;-7;3;-176437357;-1092164176;&c2=131;64;65;40;67;1;128;32;3;0;64;1;131;64;3;51;167;64;128;1025;3;0;75;12;128;63;65;40;1856636988;-184005499;&qi=LEGGIADRIA&q1=null&q2=null&q3=null&q4=null&qr=null&num=20&o=115;-38489505;-1185594668;&idV=123120;-174184881;1451299624;&TDE=&TDNE=)» riporta la definizione di monsignor Giovanni della Casa:

> Non è altro leggiadria, che una, cotal quasi luce, che risplende dalla
>   convenevolezza delle cose, che sono ben composte, e ben divisate l'una
>   con l'altra, e tutte insieme, senza la qual misura, eziandio il bene
>   non è bello, e la bellezza non è piacevole.

S’implica qui l’antica concezione platonica, e greca in generale, della corrispondenza tra bellezza e bontà. Una donna leggiadra o graziosa ha una bellezza angelica e pura, e non potrebbe far ribollire il sangue a chi la guarda. Da un lato sta l’attrattività terragna di chi è seducente, procace; dall’altro la compostezza e la leggerezza quasi celeste di una persona graziosa e leggiadra.

Giacché *winsome*, secondo il dizionario *[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/winsome)*, è prevalentemente letterario, credo che *leggiadro* ne sia una traduzione adeguata; anzi, se l’aggettivo si applicasse a un bambino, non sarebbe inappropriato neanche il diminutivo *[leggiadretto](http://www.lessicografia.it/Controller?lemma=LEGGIADRETTO_ed1&rewrite=1)*.

Scendendo di registro, troviamo poi *[carino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/carino/)*, che non ha implicazioni morali, e trasmette, nell’uso famigliare, l’idea di qualcosa di delicatamente piacevole alla vista: una bellezza non vistosa che suscita tenerezza. Inoltre, comunemente, in riferimento all’aspetto di donne o uomini, è quasi a metà strada tra *ordinario* e *bello*. Una ragazza carina non ha un aspetto sgradevole, anzi, piace a molti; ma non può nemmeno dirsi bella.

Comment: Interessante la tua disquisizione, in realtà penso che *leggiadro* sia molto più letterario  e datato di winsome. ***Winsome:*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=winsome&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwinsome%3B%2Cc0 ***Leggiadro*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leggiadro+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleggiadro%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Uhm, siamo sicuri che _Ngram_ sia un buon indicatore della percezione attuale della parola? Che, insomma, indichi con una qualche certezza che un anglofono di oggi lo percepisca come meno letterario e datato rispetto all’italiano _leggiadro_?

Comment: Anche il dizionario _Cambdrige_ marca [_winsome_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/winsome) come letterario. Di là dalla maggiore o minore frequenza nell’uso all’interno di _corpus_ non selezionato come quello di _Google Libri_, credo che il registro di _winsome_ possa essere considerato equivalente a quello di _leggiadro_. Mi soffermerei piuttosto sul significato, che non è perfettamente congruente: ma è inevitabile che qualcosa si perda nella traduzione.

Comment: Ngram, con i suoi limiti, da comunque una buona indicazione sull'uso dei termini. È' una mia impressione che ha trovato conferma in Ngram. Comunque indagherò oltre, magari chiedendo su ELU. Oxford Dictionary non lo cita come termine letterario, e tra i nostri amici inglesi è il più affidabile. Tutto ciò non toglie nulla alla tua risposta che è molto interessante.

Comment: Ti ringrazio. Non volevo ovviamente negare ogni legittimità a una ricerca su Ngram. Sicuramente il dizionario _Oxford_ è affidabilissimo. Posso però dirti che, rimanendo nell’ambito d’impressioni, benintenso, _leggiadro_ è sí un termine letterario, di registro elevato, ma non è sconosciuto a una persona di media cultura. Nell’archivio della _Repubblica_ (che va dal 1984 a oggi) _leggiadro_ si trova 452 volte; in quello del _Corriere della Sera_ (che va dal 1992 a oggi) 198 volte. Non è insomma cosí raro come può sembrare.

Comment: Aggiungo solo una cosa. Un dizionario dell’uso come il _De Mauro_ marca [_leggiadro_](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/leggiadro), nel significato di ‹dotato di bellezza armoniosa, pieno di grazia ed eleganza›, come «comune».

Comment: Leggiadro un aggettivo comune? Potresti farne una domanda qui sul sito! :)) la mia risposta è no!!

Comment: Attenzione: «comune» nel [_De Mauro_](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6) significa «usat[o] e compres[o] indipendentemente dalla professione o mestiere che si esercita o dalla collocazione regionale e […] generalmente not[o] a chiunque abbia un livello mediosuperiore di istruzione». Insomma, corrisponde a quel che dicevo sopra: «[N]on è sconosciuto a una persona di media cultura».

Comment: Confermo che leggiadro non sia poi così ricercato come termine. Una persona con diploma superiore ha sicuramente nozione della parola e non troverei bizzarro il fatto che la utilizzi se il contesto lo richiede. 
_Winsome_ non ha una diretta traduzione, si dovrebbe usare una forma composta tipo `acqua e sapone` per sottolineare l'aspetto d'innocenza.

Answer (score 3):

Probabilmente l'aggettivo italiano più vicino a *winsome* è *accattivante*, (*captivating*). Anche questo aggettivo esclude automaticamente qualsiasi associazione grossolana; non lo direi direttamente di una persona, ma per qualificarne la bellezza: "è di una bellezza accattivante".